# Vue JS - Como exibir uma lista intercalada entre propriedade e valor?

Tags: lista, vue.js, table

Tenho essa lista como objeto:

```
let app = new Vue({
 el:'#app',
 data:{
    lista:{
        nome: 'Nome Completo',
        email: 'email@email.com',
        cpf: 'xxx.xxx.xxx-xx',
        rg: 'x.xxx.xxx',
        tel: '(xx) x xxxx-xxxx'
    }
 }
});
```

E preciso exibir em uma td (numa linha só) dentro da tr e da table.
Exemplo:
Nome: Nome Completo Email: email@email.com CPF: xxx.xxx.xxx-xx RG: x.xxx.xxx Tel: (xx) x xxxx-xxxx

Mas o mais perto que cheguei foi:

```
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td v-for="(value, name, index) in lista">
                    {{name}}
                    {{value}}
                </td>
    </table>
```

Só que desse jeito o name (propriedade) fica dentro da mesma td que o valor, mas preciso que a propriedade ocupe sua própria td e o valor também.

Comment: tenta usar template ou um novo componente para o v-for

Comment: Acabei colocando duas div dentro do td, daí pude organizar melhor.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
    <tr v-for="(value, name, index) in lista">
        <td class="propriedade">{{name}}</td>
        <td class="valor">{{valor}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Se o item a ser iterado é a linha, então isso deve resolver o seu problema

Comment: Eu tentei fazer assim, mas o problema é que eu queria dispor das informações lateralmente e não verticalmente.
Daí acabei optando por usar div's dentro do td.

Answer (score 2):

Se você não vai mostrar dados tabulares, teoricamente você nem precisaria usar uma tabela para mostrar seus dados lado a lado.

Mas caso você precise do mesmo jeito, ou alguém que chegue aqui precise, você pode usar a tag `<template>` com `v-for` para renderizar tags "sem elemento-pai". Veja a [documentação](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Utilizando-lt-template-gt-com-v-for).

A tag `<template>` vai funcionar como um [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) e servir como um tag container "fantasma".

Exemplo:

```js
let app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
    dados: {
        nome: 'Nome Completo',
        email: 'email@email.com',
        cpf: 'xxx.xxx.xxx-xx',
        rg: 'x.xxx.xxx',
        tel: '(xx) x xxxx-xxxx'
    }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <template v-for="(value, name, index) in dados">
          <th>{{ name }}</th>
          <td>{{ value }}</td>
        </template>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Acabei fazendo dessa forma pra conseguir separar visualmente e conseguir fazer uma edição.

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td v-for="(value, name, index) in lista">
                    <div class="propriedade">{{name}}</div>
                    <div class="valor">{{value}}</div>
                </td>
    </table>
```

Comment: Se for fazer uma edição da pergunta, faça direto a edição na pergunta, não usa o campo resposta, porque isso inibe os outros responderem